# How to pull SQL data by top 10 in Excel table

Tags: sql, excel

I want to pull the data of the **top 10 ID** based on Excel table `Excel_table1` column `Value`, from an SQL view `SQL_view` where `original_code` **starts with** `HC` in `SQL_view`, into another Excel spreadsheet.

`Excel_table1` looks something like this:

```
ID        Value    Code
242432    10000    HC-part
242432    9900     HC-part1
924242    8900     XS
    ...
```

`SQL_view` looks like this:

```
id        Info1   Info2    Country      original_code   Date      Quantity
  
242432    XX      YY       Japan        HC-part         2020-10   150
242491    XX      YY       Japan        HC-part1        2020-10   250
    ...
```

So `Excel_table1` columns `ID` is the same as `SQL_view` column `id` and `Excel_table1` columns `Code` is the same as `SQL_view` column `original_code`

Expected output would be of format:

```
id        Info1   Info2    Country      original_code   Date      Quantity
  
242432    XX      YY       Japan        HC-part         2020-10   150
242491    XX      YY       Japan        HC-part1        2020-10   250
    ...
```

these rows from `SQL_view` have been selected because: 1) `id 242432 and 242491` are from the top 10 `ID` in `Excel_table1` AND their `original_code` **starts with** `HC`.

Comment: Can you paste the output you are expecting? This will make the question much clear to be answered.

Comment: Hi @RakhiAgrawal please see edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a query which will result the output based on the result of another sub query. So you will be needing:

1. To get the top 10 IDs from `Excel_table1` based on column `value` where the code starts with `'HC'`

```
select ID from Excel_table1 where Code like 'HC%' ORDER BY Value DESC limit 3
```

2. To get the complete data from `SQL_View` for the IDs returned in above query

```
select * from SQL_view where id in (select ID from Excel_table1 where Code like 'HC%' ORDER BY Value DESC limit 3)
```

The query under point 2 is the final one which will output you the expected results.

Hope I got your question right.

Comment: Hi Rakhi, thanks for your answer, `Excel_table1` is actually not in SQL database but in an Excel file, can we query the table in SQL database like this?

Comment: Hi @nilsinelabore, The above queries would work smooth in SQL database if you have `Ecel_table1` in there. For running SQL queries in Excel file please visit [this link](https://xltools.net/sql-queries-in-excel/). This has a very well explaination given. I believe with the tables created properly in Excel as mentioned in the link, above queries should work for you in Excel as well. Hope I got the question right. Please let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Hi Rakhi, in this case the separate Excel table is not in in SQL database. I was asking to see if we can query SQL database based on an external excel file... But thanks for your answer. I think the answer is no?

Comment: Not very sure about that. But Google helped me with this article [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4585/using-microsoft-query-in-excel-to-retreive-sql-server-data/) which explains using microsoft query in excel to retreive sql server data. Please check if this is something you want.